# Running PowerShell command Get-ADUser from Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, windows-10

I am Trying to run the PowerShell command `Get-ADUser` on my Windows 10 Pro Laptop.
I am getting below error.

```
Get-ADUser: The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.....
```

After googling I got to know I need to run command `Install-Module ActiveDirectory`, but this command given error that ActiveDirectory module not found.

I did try to install all the RSAT Tools but I see it is in `Staged` state and not sure how to move them to `Installed`. I did google this issue and not able to fix it.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "rsat*" | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, State

DisplayName                                                                         State
-----------                                                                         -----
RSAT: Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Services Tools    Staged
RSAT: BitLocker Drive Encryption Administration Utilities                       Installed
RSAT: Active Directory Certificate Services Tools                                  Staged
RSAT: DHCP Server Tools                                                            Staged
RSAT: DNS Server Tools                                                             Staged
RSAT: Failover Clustering Tools                                                    Staged
RSAT: File Services Tools                                                          Staged
RSAT: Group Policy Management Tools                                                Staged
RSAT: IP Address Management (IPAM) Client                                       Installed
RSAT: Data Centre Bridging LLDP Tools                                           Installed
RSAT: Network Controller Management Tools                                       Installed
RSAT: Network Load Balancing Tools                                              Installed
RSAT: Remote Access Management Tools                                               Staged
RSAT: Remote Desktop Services Tools                                                Staged
RSAT: Server Manager                                                            Installed
RSAT: Shielded VM Tools                                                            Staged
RSAT: Storage Migration Service Management Tools                                   Staged
RSAT: Storage Replica Module for Windows PowerShell                             Installed
RSAT: System Insights Module for Windows PowerShell                             Installed
RSAT: Volume Activation Tools                                                   Installed
RSAT: Windows Server Update Services Tools                                         Staged
```

Also from the `Settings > Apps > Optional features > Add feature` I am getting error when I try to install `RSAT: Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Services Tools`.

As per some of the seggetions I need to run the PowerShell command `Stop-Service -Name wuauserv` then install again, but it did fail in my case.

**Issue that I am facing:**

1. I want to run Get-ADUser command from Windows 10 but I am not able to.
2. I did not find a step-by-step guide which can describe how to use powershell command with ActiveDirectory on Windows 10 Pro.
3. I am not sure if I need to have the AD Domain Controller, if I need how to configure.
4. I have all the "Windows Administrative Tools" installed on my Windows 10 Laptop but not sure how to configure these tools to my Azure AD and if these tools are required for running `Get-ADUser` command.

**Details:**
**Windows:** Windows 10 Pro 21H1
**PowerShell:** version 5.1.19041

--------------------- Update --------------------------

I got the all the RSAT modules/services installed on my Windows 10 Laptop. The issue was related to the recent update to my Windows.

I have to enable below policy on my Laptop:

```
Edit Group Policy > Administrative Templates > System > Specify settings for optional component installation....

1. Select CheckBox: Enabled 
2. Select CheckBox: Download repair content and optional features directly....
```

Comment: "Staged" sounds like something a reboot might take care of :)

Comment: I did reboot but it remains in the same state, also installing from "Optional features" UI fails with error code `0x80070490`.

Comment: You have the same error if you type this ? `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0"`

Comment: Got all the RSAT features install. But not sure how to connect to Active Directory domain controller.